# Rails real time database query marquee/ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, real-time

Good day,

I would like to create a real time Newsticker/Marquee scroller for my rails app, Similar to what you would find on Sky Sports News TV channel.

I Need to be able to query the database table (which i can) and display the output in the ticker/marquee one table row at a time looping it over. Also i would like to either try display this query in real-time or very frequently and updating the output on the clients end without the page refreshing. (Similar to a chat room or twitter feed.)

Here is some basic code

Simple Query Which shows the subject and paper if the start time is < Current time and Stop time is > Current time

Model

```
 Timetable.where("start < ? AND stop > ?", Time.now, Time.now).order('id ASC').pluck(:subject, :paper)
```

Html

```
<table><tbody><% @timetables.each do |timetable| %><tr><td><%= timetable[0] %></td><td>%= timetable[1] %></td></tr><% end %></tbody></table>
```

If anyone is able to hepl or point me in the right direction, Ill really appreciate it. Thanks

At the moment i could probably use a partial to display the query and update the partial, not sure if there is a better method using any gems that will open up an event listener or socket?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem you've got here. Got me excited and I tried some things out myself!

If you want to have content refreshed on the client side (no page reload), you need to use javascript to repeatedly query the server. In Rails you'd probably go with a partial that's being rendered from both the page view and the API-view that's used in an AJAX call.

Let's assume you have a model called `Item` of which you want to show the latest 3 on your page and then fetch the latest every 5 seconds to update the page. You might want to create something that looks like the following:

*controllers/content_controller.rb*

```
class ContentController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

*views/content/show.haml*

```
%h1 Page with updated items

.updateme
  = render "items/latest"
```

*controllers/items_controller.rb*

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def index
  end
end
```

*views/items/index.haml*

```
= render "items/latest"
```

*views/items/_latest.haml*

```
- Item.last(3).each do |item|
  = item.subject
```

Last but not least you will need to add javascript that calls the index for items

*javascripts/update.js*

```
function updateItems() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/items",
  }).done(function(data) {
    $("div.updateme").html(data)
  });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval(function(){
    updateItems();
  }, 5000);
});
```

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction :)